# Best way to optimize this function

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I have a function as below which traverse through a large chunk of json data.

```
const findMakeAndModel = (make, model) => {
  let foundMakeModel = false;
  makeModel.map(value => {
    if (value.makeCode === make.toUpperCase()) {
      value.model.map(makeModel => {
          if (makeModel.modelValue === `${make} - ${model}`) {
            foundMakeModel = true;
          }
      })
    }
  });
  return foundMakeModel
}
```

Though it works, I would like to have the time cut down the time it takes. I tried to return inside the `if (makeModel.modelValue === ${make} - ${model})` condition but somehow it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Above json is what I'm using but actual one is much much more larger. That's why traversing through takes time.

Comment: Don't call `map()` if you're not using the return value. It creates a new list. Use `forEach()` if you just want to loop for side effect.

Comment: As @Barmar mentioned, use `forEach()` to iterate. Also move the  `make.toUpperCase()` and also `${make} - ${model}` above the loop, to avoid calling in each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to stop a `map` or `forEach` loop in the middle. If you want to stop the loop once you've found an element that meets a condition, you need to use a `for` loop.

Or you can use the `find` method. This returns the first element that meets a condition, so it will stop searching once that's found. You can then just check whether this is not null and return that.

Also, your variable is not an array, it's an object. You need to use `data.makeModel` to get to the property with the array.

```js
const findMakeAndModel = (make, model) => {
  let makeUpper = make.toUpperCase(); // don't repeat this every time
  let makeModelCombined = `${make} - ${model}`; // or this
  let foundMakeModel =
    data.makeModel.find(value => value.makeCode === makeUpper &&
      value.model.find(makeModel => makeModel.modelValue === makeModelCombined))
  return foundMakeModel !== null;
}

let data = {
    "makeModel": [{
            "makeId": 1,
            "makeCode": "NISSAN",
            "makeValue": "Nissan",
            "model": [{
                    "modelCode": "NIS032",
                    "modelValue": "Nissan - Cube"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "NIS012",
                    "modelValue": "Nissan - March"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "NIS033",
                    "modelValue": "Nissan - Note CVT"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "makeId": 2,
            "makeCode": "OPEL",
            "makeValue": "Opel",
            "model": [{
                    "modelCode": "OPE005",
                    "modelValue": "Opel - Zafira"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "OPE009",
                    "modelValue": "Opel - Astra"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "makeId": 21,
            "makeCode": "DAIHATSU",
            "makeValue": "Daihatsu",
            "model": [{
                    "modelCode": "DAI006",
                    "modelValue": "Daihatsu - Terios 7"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "DAI015",
                    "modelValue": "Daihatsu - Extol"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "DAI007",
                    "modelValue": "Daihatsu - YRV Turbo"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "DAI010",
                    "modelValue": "Daihatsu - M303RS"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "makeId": 31,
            "makeCode": "MITSUBISHI",
            "makeValue": "Mitsubishi",
            "model": [
                {
                    "modelCode": "MIT042",
                    "modelValue": "Mitsubishi - Lancer Evo VIII"
                },
                {
                    "modelCode": "MIT009",
                    "modelValue": "Mitsubishi - i"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
};

console.log(findMakeAndModel('Nissan', 'March'));
```